# How to produce struct addrinfo from struct sockaddr?

Tags: c, networking, sockets

I have a struct sockaddr and need to make a struct addrinfo (specifically that, because that's what some other API wants). The IP address may be IPv4 or IPv6. What's the best way to handle that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [man 3 getaddrinfo](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=getaddrinfo&sektion=3),

```
struct addrinfo {
    int              ai_flags;
    int              ai_family;
    int              ai_socktype;
    int              ai_protocol;
    size_t           ai_addrlen;
    struct sockaddr *ai_addr;
    char            *ai_canonname;
    struct addrinfo *ai_next;
};
```

A `struct addrinfo` contains more information than just a `struct sockaddr` does.  Given a `struct sockaddr_in`, you can have some of this information (`.ai_family = AF_INET, .ai_addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)`).  Whether this is sufficient depends on what the other API is looking for.

Comment: Yes, creating a new addrinfo, putting the sockaddr in *ai_addr and filling the other fields with reasonable values seem the way to go.